# remote into a Linux GUI

Tags: user-interface

I have two RHEL-7.5 instances - one in public subnet & other in private subnet @AWS.

Both the instances have GNOME GUI Enabled & XRDP Installed which has setup GUI at both instances.

I need to know the steps of how can I access & login to the GUI console of private instance from GUI console of public instance.

Kindly let me know the steps.

-Kunal

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open the RDP Ports (3389 in most cases) in security group attached to those instances. Then you can use any RDP client like vnc viewer to access the instance gui using host details and credentials.